# How a string is implicitly type casted into a character?

Tags: c, string, compiler-errors, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
 {   char a="aaa";
     printf("%c \n",a);
     return 0;
 }
```

The o/p is:-

> $

How does this code runs internally? Is there a predefined way for all the compilers or it changes from compiler to compiler?
PS:-I have seen questions related to this program that in which phase of the compiler the above program gives an error...and when i tried to run this program on two different compilers it only gives a warning instead of an error..So according to you ideally this program should give an error in which phase of the compiler?

Comment: `char a="aaa";` is plain wrong and doesn't make sense. Your compilers warns you BTW.

Comment: you have used wrong syntax and it is breaking compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not valid C. Initialization `char a="aaa";` is a *constraint violation*. Standard C language does not support implicit conversions from pointer types to integer types. I'm sure your compiler issued a diagnostic message about it. After that the behavior of the code is no longer defined by C language.

The behavior can still be defined by your compiler, as an extension, which means that yes, it can change from one compiler (that allows it) to another.

Comment: The only correct answer so far. The assignment is a constraint violation because it is not one of the valid forms of simple assignment 6.5.16.1.

Comment: I have seen questions related to this program that in which phase of the compiler the above program gives an error...and when i tried to run this program on two different compilers it only gives a warning instead of an error..So according to you ideally this program should give an error in which phase of the compiler?

Comment: @ashishmalgawa The standard only says that the compiler must give a "diagnostic", the standard doesn't separate errors and warnings - both count as "diagnostics", so both your compilers are compliant, although it is IMO questionable practice to just give a warning. The compiler should give this diagnostic during the "compilation phase" - C does not specify the phases of the actual code compilation. Once the compiler has created a translation unit (resolved pre-processing etc), it is free to go through the code in any way it wants.

Comment: since the data type is checked in lexical analysis phase when the symbol table is formed...this "diagnostic" will be created in the lexical analysis phase right?

Comment: @ashish malgawa: No. Error in this code is caused by type incompatibility. Lexical analysis knows nothing about types. This is a semantic error.